# MS access 2016 email to multiple recipients issue

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have a code in `msaccess` that is used for sending emails. The email Distribution List is taken from the table.
The table data is as below

```
NAME     |   Distribution List

myname1  |   myname1@xyz.com
```

The code is working fine when the data is as above. However, when I try to put multiple distribution list for one contact the functionality fails. example- if my table data is like below,the code fails to recognize mail list.

```
NAME     |   Distribution List
-------------------------------
myname1  |   myname1@xyz.com ; mysecondemail@xyz.com
```

Please help with suggestions. I'm trying to accommodate all the distribution list in 1 row per contact.

Comment: What code - I don't see anything to look at.

Comment: How are you sending email - via Outlook object or some smtp process? What is error message if any?